# Why i'm getting exception InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

The message:

Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Effect' to type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.BasicEffect'

The code:

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in xwingModel.Meshes)
            {
                // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well 
                // as our camera and projection.
                foreach (BasicEffect Effects in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    Effects.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    Effects.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                        //Matrix.CreateRotationY(modelRotation)
                         Matrix.CreateTranslation(modelPosition);
                    Effects.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition,
                        Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
                    Effects.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                        MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), aspectRatio,
                        1.0f, 10000.0f);
                }
                // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
                mesh.Draw();
            }
```

The exception is on this part:

BasicEffect Effects

The full exception message:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Effect' to type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.BasicEffect'.
  Source=MyFlightSimulator
  StackTrace:
       at MyFlightSimulator.Game1.DrawModel() in Game1.cs:line 279
       at MyFlightSimulator.Game1.Draw(GameTime gameTime) in Game1.cs:line 133
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DrawFrame()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.HostIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameHost.OnIdle()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.RunOneFrame()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.ApplicationIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(Int32 grfidlef)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.Run()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
       at MyFlightSimulator.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 15
  InnerException:
```

Game1 line 279 is:

```
foreach (BasicEffect Effects in mesh.Effects)
```

Program line 15 is:

```
game.Run();
```

This is the complete method code:

```
private void DrawModel()
        {
            Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[xwingModel.Bones.Count];
            xwingModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

            // Draw the model. A model can have multiple meshes, so loop.
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in xwingModel.Meshes)
            {
                // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well 
                // as our camera and projection.
                foreach (BasicEffect Effects in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    Effects.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    Effects.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                        //Matrix.CreateRotationY(modelRotation)
                         Matrix.CreateTranslation(modelPosition);
                    Effects.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition,
                        Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
                    Effects.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                        MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), aspectRatio,
                        1.0f, 10000.0f);
                }
                // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Updated my question with full code and if i change it to Effect in the foreach then Effects dosent have all the properties in the next lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some or all elements of mesh.Effects are not a BasicEffect but an Effect object

Try this

```
foreach (Effect ItemEffect in mesh.Effects)
{
   if ( (ItemEffect is BasicEffect) == false)
       continue;

    BasicEffect Effects = (BasicEffect)ItemEffect;

    Effects.EnableDefaultLighting();
    Effects.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *

    Matrix.CreateTranslation(modelPosition);
    Effects.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition,Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
    Effects.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                    MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), aspectRatio,
                    1.0f, 10000.0f);
}
```

Comment: Updated my question with full code and if i change it to Effect in the foreach then Effects dosent have all the properties in the next lines.

Answer (score 2):

As described in this post: [XNA Apply effect on BasicEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597925/xna-apply-effect-on-basiceffect) not all Effects are BasicEffects.

```
foreach(BasicEffect basicEffect in mesh.Effects.OfType<BasicEffect>())
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What type of objects are contained in `mesh.Effects`? From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.basiceffect.aspx), [`BasicEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.basiceffect.aspx) inherits from `Effect`, so if all of the elements in `mesh.Effects` are of the type `BasicEffect`, the code should work.

Most likely an element in `mesh.Effects` is **not** a `BasicEffect`.

Double check what is in that list, or make sure you only run your code on the `BasicEffect`s by casting them using the [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator and checking if they are not null, in which case they are a `BasicEffect`

```
foreach (BasicEffect Effects in mesh.Effects)
{
     BasicEffect basicEffect = Effects as BasicEffect;
     if (basicEffect != null)
     {
          //Effects is a BasicEffect, run code on basicEffect
     }
}
```

You can also use [LINQ's `OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) to select only the effects in the mesh that are `BasicEffect`s

```
foreach (BasicEffect Effects in mesh.Effects.OfType<BasicEffect>());
{
     //Run code on Effects
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not every member of the set is castable to BasicEffect but you can avoid those:

```
foreach(var effect in mesh.Effects.Where(e => e.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(Effect).ToList())
    YourFunctionOrWhatever();
```

If you're reading this, check Martijn's answer instead.  It's prettier :)